# ANTLR lexer disabling tokens then reenabling them not working as expected

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

So i have a lexer with a token defined so that on a boolean property it is enabled/disabled

I create an input stream and parse a text. My token is called `PHRASE_TEXT` and should match anything falling within this pattern `'"' ('\\' ~[] |~('\"'|'\\')) '"' {phraseEnabled}?`

I tokenize `"foo bar"`  and as expected I get a single token. After setting the property to `false` on the lexer and calling `setInputStream` on it with the same text I get `"foo , bar"` so 2 tokens instead of one. This is also expected behavior.

The problem comes when setting the property to `true` again. I would expect the same text to tokenize to the whole 1 token `"foo bar"` but instead is tokenized to the 2 tokens from before. Is this a bug on my part? What am I doing wrong here? I tried using new instances of the tokenizer and reusing the same instance but it doesn't seem to work either way. Thanks in advance.

Edit : Part of my grammar follows below

```
grammar LuceneQueryParser;

@header{package com.amazon.platformsearch.solr.queryparser.psclassicqueryparser;}

@lexer::members {
    public boolean phrases = true;
}

@parser::members {
    public boolean phraseQueries = true;
}

mainQ : LPAREN query RPAREN
      | query
      ;

query : not ((AND|OR)? not)* ;

andClause : AND ;
orClause  : OR ;

not : NOT? modifier? clause;

clause : qualified                        
       | unqualified                          
       ;

unqualified : LBRACK range_in LBRACK
            | LCURL range_out RCURL
            | truncated
            | {phraseQueries}? quoted
            | LPAREN query RPAREN
            | normal
            ;

truncated : TERM_TEXT_TRUNCATED;
range_in  : (TERM_TEXT|STAR) TO (TERM_TEXT|STAR);
range_out : (TERM_TEXT|STAR) TO (TERM_TEXT|STAR);

qualified : TERM_TEXT COLON unqualified ;

normal : TERM_TEXT;
quoted : PHRASE_TEXT;

modifier : PLUS
         | MINUS
         ;

PHRASE_TEXT : '"' (ESCAPE|~('\"'|'\\'))+ '"' {phrases}?;
TERM_TEXT : (TERM_CHAR|ESCAPE)+;
TERM_CHAR  : ~(' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\u3000'
           | '\\' | '\'' | '(' | ')' | '[' | ']' | '{' | '}'
           | '+' | '-' | '!' | ':' | '~' | '^'
           | '*' | '|' | '&' | '?' );


ESCAPE : '\\' ~[];
```

The problem seems to be that after i set the phrases to false, and then to true again, no more tokens seem to be recognized as PHRASE_TEXT. I know that as a guideline i should define my grammars to be unambiguous but this is basically the way it has to end up looking : tokenizing a string with quotes in 2 different modes, depending on the situation.

Comment: I would need to see more of the grammar and the calling code in order to answer this question.

Comment: You might want to look into ANTLR4's support for [lexical modes](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules), and try to trigger that switching mechanism from your code. I believe the feature was intended to support situations such as embedding PHP inside HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna have to update this with an answer a colleague of mine helpfully pointed out. The lexer generated class has a static DFA[] array shared between all instances of the class. Once the property was set to false instead of the default true the decision tree was apparently changed for all object instances. A fix for this was to have to separate DFA[] arrays for both the true and false instances of the property i was modifying. I think making that array not static would be too expensive and i really can't think about another fix.